# How to create an object of subclass in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to create an object of subclass which is not static in the main, but not able to do. Does anyone tried the same?

```
package com.example;

import com.example.SubClassExample.MainClass.SubClass;

public class SubClassExample {

    static class MainClass {
        public int mca;
        protected int mcb;
        private int mcc;

        SubClass sc = new SubClass();

        public class SubClass {
            public int sca;
            protected int scb;
            private int scc;

            void method() {
                mca = 10;
                mcb = 20;
                mcc = 30;

                sca = 10;
                scb = 20;
                scc = 30;

                System.out.println("Subclass: " + mca + " " + mcb + " " + mcc + " ");
                System.out.println("Subclass: " + sca + " " + scb + " " + scc + " ");
            }

        }

        void method() {
            mca = 100;
            mcb = 200;
            mcc = 300;

            sc.sca = 100;
            sc.scb = 200;
            sc.scc = 300;

            System.out.println("MainClass: " + mca + " " + mcb + " " + mcc + " ");
            System.out.println("MainClass: " + sc.sca + " " + sc.scb + " " + sc.scc + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MainClass obj = new MainClass();
        obj.method();
        obj.sc.method();

        SubClass obj1 = new obj.SubClass(); //Getting ERROR here, tried so many like
                    //MainClass.clas.SubClass, obj.class.SubClass, Subclass() but still not able 
                    //to do. As it is a public subclass, cant we able to create an object of 
                    //that class
        obj1.method();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Subclass instance = new MainClass().new SubClass();
```

or in your case

```
Subclass instance = obj.new SubClass();
```

You need the instance of the parent class to create instance of inner non-static class.

Comment: In the above code obj is already instance of MainClass(), but still not able to do, any reason ?

Comment: Thanks got it :), SubClass obj1 = obj.new SubClass();

Comment: @Suman thanks for the comment I got it too :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SubClass obj1 = new obj.SubClass(); //Getting ERROR here, tried so many like
```

You can't put a `new` before the `obj`:instance of `MyClass`. It actually doesn't make sense. This is because the object of the inner class is quietly connected to the object of the outer class that it was made from. A declaring `obj.new InnerClass()` has the same equivalent meaning of `obj.innerInstance`: referencing the new inner instance by the instance of  outer class.

That is why, this line should be: `SubClass obj1 = obj.new SubClass();`

Answer (score 1):

As `SubClass` is not static so you need to create new instance.

```
MainClass obj = new MainClass();
SubClass obj1 = obj.new SubClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

why you made main class static and in my code i must make Widow class static to make code run
"

```
public class WoodenProducts {
/*
String treeType;
 int treeAge;

 */
double meterPrice;

 public WoodenProducts(){
     meterPrice = 100;

}


 class Widow extends WoodenProducts{

}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Widow W = new WoodenProducts.Widow();

    System.out.println(" meter price is " + W.meterPrice);


}
```

}
"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).